# Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081 react-native

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to run a react-native application using the command `npm run android` , but everytime I do it I am getting the below error `Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081`. I am using M1 MacBook Air 2020. Even I tried running through Metro but no use and I have tried `./gradlew clean` but also no use, still getting the same error.

Comment: once you try to install with android studio.